# How to modify only one caption in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to know if it is possible for someone to help me on captions on ggplot2.

```
d.solo<-ggplot(data=dens, aes(x=Textura_do_Solo, y=Densidade))+
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Tipo_de_Solo)), outlier.color = "black", 
outlier.shape = 16, outlier.alpha = 1)+
xlab("Soil texture")+
ylab("Wood density (kg/m³)")+
ylim(250,700)+
theme_classic()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", family="serif"))+
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", family="serif"))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family ="serif" ))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="serif"))+
theme(legend.position="right", legend.text=element_text(family="serif", 
size=10), legend.title = element_text(family="serif", size=10))+
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Clay","Medium","Sand"),
               breaks=c(1,2,3))+
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Type of Soil", title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))+
scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Neossolo","Cambissolo","Argissolo","Latossolo","Plintossolo","Gleissolo","Espodossolo"), values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

This code generated the graph bellow:

[image]

I added some parameters with this code:

```
d.solo2<-d.solo+scale_fill_manual(labels =c("Neossolo","Cambissolo","Argissolo","Latossolo","Plintossolo","Gleissolo","Espodossolo"), values=c("yellow4", "yellow1", "green2", "forestgreen","blue4", "grey36", "chocolate"))

d.solo2+ geom_hline(aes(color= "Mean Wood Density (463.9 kg/m³)", yintercept = mean(dens$Densidade)), linetype = 2) + 
  scale_color_manual("", values = "red")
```

So that my chart would look like this:

[image]

I used the code below for the caption to be below the chart:

```
theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(family="serif", size=10))
```

[image]

However he brings the two legends down the graph, and I would like the legend with the type of soil still remains in the original position, so I wanted to change ownership only the last "caption" made.

I tried several arguments as guide_legend among others, however I did not succeed.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you run `dput(dens)` then paste the output in your question?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to extract one of the legends and then use `grid.arrange` to compose both

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = class)) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 30, col = "red")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "left"))

# extract guide-box
leg    <- get_legend(p)
# get the colour legend only
botleg <- leg[3,]
# plot
grid.arrange(p + guides(colour = guide_legend("none")), botleg, 
             layout_matrix = matrix(c(1,1,1,3,2,3), nrow = 2, byrow = T),
             heights = c(7/8, 1/8))
```

As you can see, it needs finetuning...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I've been in doubt about these grid.arrange arguments, do I need to create a layout_matrix or can I just use the legend.position argument to move the caption to the middle of the chart?

Comment: You would have to use the a `layout_matrix`. Updated my code slightly.